# Like operation returns no rows on nvarchar column filter if the column data start with numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `nvarchar(50)` column in SQL Server table and data like this:

```
123abc
234abc
456abc
```

My query:

```
select * 
from table 
where col like '%abc'
```

Expected result : all rows should be returned
Actual result: No rows are returned

Works fine if the column is `varchar` but returns no rows if the type is `nvarchar`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You probably have spaces at the end of your data.  Take a look at this example.

```
Declare @Temp Table(col nvarchar(50))

Insert Into @Temp(col) Values(N'123abc')
Insert Into @Temp(col) Values(N'456abc ')

Select * From @Temp Where Col Like '%abc'
```

When you run the code above, you will only get the 123 row because the 456 row has a space on the end of it.

When you run the code shown below, you will get the data you expect.

```
Declare @Temp Table(col nvarchar(50))

Insert Into @Temp(col) Values(N'123abc')
Insert Into @Temp(col) Values(N'456abc ')

Select * From @Temp Where rtrim(Col) Like '%abc'
```

According to the documentation regarding LIKE in books on line (emphasis mine):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Pattern Matching by Using LIKE

LIKE supports ASCII pattern matching and Unicode pattern matching. When all arguments (match_expression, pattern, and escape_character, if present) are ASCII character data types, ASCII pattern matching is performed. If any one of the arguments are of Unicode data type, all arguments are converted to Unicode and Unicode pattern matching is performed. **When you use Unicode data (nchar or nvarchar data types) with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant**; however, for non-Unicode data, trailing blanks are not significant. Unicode LIKE is compatible with the ISO standard. ASCII LIKE is compatible with earlier versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 6):

for `nvarchar` type you can use select like this :-

```
select * from Table where ColumnName like N'%abc%'
```

Comment: for some reason only this worked for me on a DELETE query, putting N after LIKE instead of the other answers with no N. Same case of extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no spaces at the end of the value? You can do this to remove the white space:

```
select *
from yourTable
where rtrim(yourcolumn) like '%abc'
```

If you don't want to use the `RTRIM` and the `LIKE` together you can also use:

```
Select * 
From yourTable 
Where charindex('abc', col) > 0
```

From Microsoft about using [LIKE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

If you know the starting position of the 'abc' string then you can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
Select *
From yourTable 
Where substring(Col, 4, 3) = 'abc'
```

But then you can use charindex and substring together and you do not have to worry about white space:

```
select *
from yourTable
where substring(col, charindex('abc', col), 3) = 'abc'
```

Comment: Agree, but it works fine if the type is varchar. With out using rtrim. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use charindex, see updated answer as far as the using LIKE see the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: +1 for including more info based on feed back.  Your charindex suggestion is not equivalent to the rtrim query because charindex will return the row if the search string is anywhere within the data, not just the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work just fine, but you can also try.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (COL LIKE '%abc%')
```

In case there are characters you cannot see after the 'abc' part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine. You can try.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM "table"
WHERE CAST("col" AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to document some of the ASCII vs Unicode weirdness:

```
-- ascii like
if 'Non rational ' like 'Non[ --]rational%'  print 'like' else  print 'not like'

-- unicode like
if N'Non rational ' like N'Non[ --]rational%' print 'like' else  print 'not like'

-- unicode like, trailing space removed
if N'Non rational' like N'Non[ --]rational%' print 'like' else  print 'not like'

-- unicode like, different wildcard
 if N'Non rational ' like N'Non_rational%' print 'like' else  print 'not like'
```

Produces the following:

```
like
not like
not like
like
```