# SQL Server string comparison: nvarchar vs. varchar

Tags: sql-server

I understand that SQL pads strings when performing comparisons, but I'm wondering why there is a difference in the behaviour between nvarchar and varchar data types.

I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table_1]([F1] [nvarchar](10) NULL)
CREATE TABLE [Table_2]([F1] [varchar](10) NULL)
```

and inserted some text with trailing blanks:

```
INSERT INTO [Table_1]([F1]) VALUES ('abc   ')
INSERT INTO [Table_2]([F1]) VALUES ('abc   ')
```

Selecting DATALENGTH on each confirms that the trailing blanks are present in the data - 12 bytes for the nvarchar field and 6 bytes for the varchar.

So, as expected, for the nvarchar field, select with = 'abc' returns the record but like 'abc' does not:

```
SELECT [F1] FROM [Table_1] WHERE [F1] = 'abc' --> 1 row returned
SELECT [F1] FROM [Table_1] WHERE [F1] like 'abc'  --> 0 row returned
```

However, the same select on the varchar field behaves differently:

```
SELECT [F1] FROM [Table_2] WHERE [F1] = 'abc' --> 1 row returned
SELECT [F1] FROM [Table_2] WHERE [F1] like 'abc' --> 1 row returned
```

The row is returned for both '=' and 'like'. I just wondered why nvarchar and varchar are different in this respect.

Thanks

Comment: I was about to write an answer but than found this post containing the needed answer [Like operation returns no rows on nvarchar column filter if the column data start with numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200125/like-operation-returns-no-rows-on-nvarchar-column-filter-if-the-column-data-star) due to the unhappy title ( which IMHO can't be changed due to missing acceptance) not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the post. It answers my question, thanks.  

So I tried  

`SELECT [F1] FROM [Table_2] WHERE [F1] like N'abc'`  

and sure enough it forced Unicode comparison and no rows were returned.