# Like statement in SQL Server query not returning all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a database table with a column of type `nvarchar(max)` and the value '17KAAKSPN13'

When querying the table using testcolumn like '%17KA%' no results are returned. If I query using '%17KAA%' I do get a result.

To test this, create a simple table and perform the queries below and see that the second query does not return any results:

**Update:** Server collation: Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].testtable(
    testcolumn [nvarchar](max) NULL
) 

insert into [dbo].testtable (testcolumn) values('17KAAKSPN13')

SELECT * FROM [dbo].testtable 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].testtable WHERE testcolumn like '%17KA%'
```

Result:
[image: No results returned when using like query]

EDIT:

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27d39f7dc41b5a3309260ef004cfc898) is an example of it not working.  I'm adding this as an edit because there are many comments and two inappropriate fiddles.  The issue seems to have to do with collation.

Comment: it is working as expected with `%17KA%`- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9ba05/1

Comment: You've done a great job adding an example. Could you tell use whats your collation? `SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));  `

Comment: Sure, server collation is Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS

Comment: And the AA is another form for Å in Danish, which means the `AA` you stored is treated as an Å, not AA. I don't know Danish, but an identical question has appeared before

Comment: Sure, that must be the case. Switching to a different collation returns results: 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].testtable WHERE testcolumn like '%17KA%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI

Comment: The actual stored value didn't change. The collation controls how characters are matched or ordered though, which means that `AA` will be treated as `Å`. You should change the column's collation to something else. Your queries are using *ASCII* string literals too. You should use the `N` prefix to create Unicode literals when there's any chance of conversion. Collations are also used to convert `varchar` values between codepages

Comment: If data is stored as Å, why don't i get a result when querying LIKE '%17KÅ%' ? That only gives a result if i use latin1 collation, and not danish_norwegian

Comment: Precisely because `AA` is treated as `Å` in Danish and Norwegian collations. You should permanently change the column's collation to `Latin1`. *And* use Unicode string literals to avoid accidental codepage conversions

Comment: Try it by `N` ==> **Like N'%17KA%''**

Comment: The `AA` is still stored as `AA`, not `Å`. You can confirm that with `select cast(testcolumn as varbinary(max)) from dbo.testtable;` - the `AA` characters are returned as `0x41004100` whereas `Å` would have returned `0xC500`.

Comment: Its working perfectly.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b93acbe0a9455326bad7358854dfb701 can you please check again

Answer (score 0):

Coming from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802337/13927312

Try and see if adding N before your pattern (mark it as Unicode) makes any difference. It might not explain this behavior but can solve your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].testtable WHERE testcolumn like N'%17KA%'
```

Comment: This is quite clearly not the answer - its the collation which is the issue as discussed in the comments. If you try your answer you see it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for COLLATE clause to convert into a collation, which makes the `LIKE` to work out.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [dbo].testtable WHERE testcolumn collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
like '%17KA%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

[From MSDN on collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Character literals and variables are assigned the default collation of
> the current database.
> Column references are assigned the definition
> collation of the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in Norwegian and Danish, "AA" is a different character from "A".  So you cannot search for it as just an "A".

The reason is that "AA" is a way of representing Å.

So, your code is working correctly.  You can convert to a different collation where `'AA'` is just `'A'` following `'A'`.